# How to force to send data to router (on L3) instead sending directly? (on L2)

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, arp, netmask

I have a public IP-addr on one machine:

```
a.b.c.156/32
```

The GW is a.b.c.133 (which is in the /27 network with its gateway a.b.c.129)

I statically added an arp route:

```
sudo arp -an
a.b.c.133 at ab:cd:ef:12:34:56 [ether] PERM on eth0
```

If I ping from `a.b.c.156/32`:

```
From a.b.c.133: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host (New nexthop: a.b.c.129)
```

then:

```
sudo arp -an
a.b.c.129 at aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff [ether] on eth0 # !<------ why? (it is even not from the same network)
a.b.c.133 at ab:cd:ef:12:34:56 [ether] PERM on eth0
```

How to prevent it from sending arp behind my router (a.b.c.133)? So that a.b.c.129 would be accessible only over IP level 3, not like a subnet?

## Update:

The network structure:

```
provider's GW (a.b.c.129/27) <--- my host (a.b.c.133/27) <--- my second host (a.b.c.156/32)
                                                      <--- my third host (a.b.c.151/32)
                                                      ...
(a.b.c.x - public IP)
```

How to prevent the hosts behind `"my host (a.b.c.133)"` from sending arp to the `"provider's GW (a.b.c.129/27)"`, but using the routing instead? So that a.b.c.129 would be accessible only over IP level 3, not directly? So how to isolate the second, third ... hosts from sending arp to the`"provider's GW (a.b.c.129/27)"`?

## Update 2:

I have the following in the `"route -n"`:

```
Dest.     GW.       Mask             Flags Metrics Ref Interface
0.0.0.0   a.b.c.133 0.0.0.0          UG    0       0   eth0
a.b.c.133 0.0.0.0   255.255.255.255  UH    0       0   eth0
```

Update 3:

```
===============
my host (a.b.c.133/27):
> ip r
a.b.c.151 dev vmbr0  scope link  # third host
a.b.c.156 dev vmbr0  scope link  # second host
192.168.1.0/24 dev vmbr1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1  # local network
default via a.b.c.129 dev vmbr0  # provider's gw

> ip n
a.b.c.129 dev vmbr0 lladdr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF REACHABLE
a.b.c.156 dev vmbr0 lladdr AB:CD:EF:12:34:56 PERMANENT
a.b.c.151 dev vmbr0 lladdr A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6 PERMANENT
===============
my second host (a.b.c.156/32):
> ip r
default via a.b.c.133 dev eth0
a.b.c.133 dev eth0 scope link

> ip n # before "ping a.b.c.129" or "ping 8.8.8.8"
a.b.c.133 dev eth0 lladdr F1:E2:D3:C4:B5:A6 PERMANENT

> ip n # after "ping a.b.c.129" or "ping 8.8.8.8"
a.b.c.129 dev eth0 lladdr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF REACHABLE # after some minutes idle => STALE
a.b.c.133 dev eth0 lladdr F1:E2:D3:C4:B5:A6 PERMANENT
===============
other hosts the similar to "my second host"
```

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're talking about. On what machine did you statically add an ARP entry and why? What is the "it" you are talking about in the last paragraph?

Comment: I see. updated the question.

Comment: Something is still not making sense. ARP is an Ethernet thing. Your picture shows the second and third hosts on a separate Ethernet network from the the provider's GW. So they *can't* send ARP requests to them. What does "behind" exactly mean here? Is "my host" a router? If so, is it the default gateway for the second and third hosts?

Comment: I want the "my host (a.b.c.133)" be a router. It is a usual computer.

Comment: Then you need to add *routes*, not ARP entries. And a.b.c.133 needs to be the default gateway for the second and third hosts. (And "my host" needs to be on a subnet along with the second and third hosts so they can exchange traffic.)

Comment: if I set "my second host" etc. to the /27 subnet then it still knows the Provider's GW, and vice versa. (Updated the question)

Comment: Right, but if you want to use "my host" as a router, then you need to add routes to the second and third hosts telling it to use "my host" as a router.

Comment: yep, I did it:
ip route add default via a.b.c.133 dev eth0. And this is the strange thing: second host knows who is the router, why it accesses the provider's router over arp? I want that all stuff behind "my host" would be forced to route, not to connect directly to other hosts in front of "my host" (i.e. providers' router), but still can directly access other "third host, ... etc.".

Comment: That will work, so long as the hosts are configured inside the same subnet as a.b.c.133 or otherwise have a route to it.

Comment: still, doesn't work. The second/third etc. provider's gw add the MAC-address as long it sends something to it or to somewhere outside through it.

Comment: Can you paste your current config? Can each machine reach its default gateway?

Comment: I have done config dynamically (not via /etc/network/interfaces) because I need to change all the time the settings. So what do you mean config: "ip r", "ip n"? Yes, each machine can reach its default gw and further (I can reach the Internet).

Comment: updated: added the configuration from "ip n", "ip r"

Comment: a.b.c.129 is the default gateway, but there's no route to a.b.c.129 nor are both hosts on a common network.

Comment: default gw to the "my host" and it has the "a.b.c.129" as default (see "my host" ">ip r"). Why should the "second host" has "a.b.c.129" as a default gw?, it has "my host" as a default gw

Answer (score 0):

```
a.b.c.129 at aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff [ether] on eth0 # !<------ why? 
                                          (it is even not from the same network)
```

It on the same network. Otherwise you would not see the hardware address of the node. If you were on different networks you would only see the MAC address of your router*. Logically separated subnets can be on the same physical network. Nothing prevents them from using the shortest physical path. The provider's gateway and your gateway share a subnet in the example.

If you wish to force all traffic via your gateway, I think you'll need to create firewall rules on the hosts.

* You would see the MAC address of **+'**. (a cross represents a NIC)

```
   [local subnet]---------+' local gw +"
                                      |
                                      |
     [ remote subnet]----+. remote gw +,
```

Comment: Which firewall rules do you mean? It should not be a REJECT/DROP rules, otherwise the traffic will just be rejected and no communication will be possible. I need a rule, that forces the second and etc. hosts to send traffic via router, not directly.

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/345111/iptables-target-to-route-packet-to-specific-interface) outlines a way to force some traffic through a given interface. Similar configurations can be done for addresses. Do your research, try at least one method, then ask a new question about iptables if needed. Don't forget to state your actual objectives (*I'm guessing* such as isolating your hosts from the provider's GW). Good luck.